# Integral over $B_1^n(0)$

Tags: integration, analysis, gamma-function

Evaluate $I = \int_{B_1^n(0)} (a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n)^{2/3}$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here's where I'm at, following a hint:

Consider an orthonormal transformation $T$ with the first row equal to $(a_1/\alpha,\cdots,a_n/\alpha)$, where $\alpha = \sqrt{\sum a_j^2}$. Then, if $y = Tx$, $\alpha y_1 = \sum a_jx_j$. Now we have $I = \int _{B_1^n(0)}(\alpha y_1)^{2/3}$. But here's where I am not sure what to do with this $y_1$ to actually evaluate the integral? Why does $T$ need to be orthonormal, not just orthogonal?

Thanks

Comment: would you mind to explain what $B^n_1(0)$is? Presumably something like the n-dimensional unit ball witt the origin excluded? the orthonormality condition is necessary to keep the measure invariant as far as i remember. The integral in the end is not difficult, it's just the volume of the n-1 dimensional unit ball multplied by elementary one dimensional integral.

Comment: Sorry, it is the n-dimensional unit ball about the origin.